# how do you use computed property names in HOCs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, higher-order-components

I have a HOC like so:

```
export const authenticateUser = WrappedComponent => (props) => {
  return props.authenticated ? <WrappedComponent {...props} /> : <div> Please log in to continue </div>
}
```

but this is semi reusable. I would like to reuse this HOC in many places but instead of hardcoding `props.authenticated` I would like to do something like `props[authenticator]` where authenticator is what ever I pass down. for example

I would like it to be the following

`props.admin`

`props.authenticated`

`props.manager`

on different occasions?

how can I pass this down?

i have tried adding it as a second argument/prop

but when I do this

```
const Auth = authenticateUser(welcomeScreen, 'admin')
```

it breaks

any ideas?

Comment: what error do you receive

Comment: How do you expect `Auth` to be used? Is `'admin'` the name of a prop? How do you pass the value of a prop then?